# Hex String to Reg File/Import Fail

Tags: batch-file

### Explanation

---

Okay, so this is the gist of what I'm trying to accomplish. I wrote a batch file named *str2hex2reg.bat* (refer below for batch script) which is called during the installation of a program, like this:

`str2hex2reg.bat C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Temp\libFile.dll`

This batch file will then take this filepath as a string and convert it to hex and then save it's output to a registry file which will look something like the following:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Company\Program\component\settings] 
"FullPath"=hex:43,3A,5C,55,73,65,72,73,5C,44,65,76,69,6E,5C,41,70,70,44,61,74,61,5C,4C,6F,63,61,6C,5C,54,65,6D,70,5C,6C,69,62,46,69,6C,65,2E,64,6C,6C
```

I was quite pleased I wrote this batch file to function like this and work correctly up until this point.

### Problem

---

Okay so here's where I run into my problem. The key `FullPath` has the string which is converted to the hex output and when you open the reg file everything looks correct; however, I know the `FullPath` key needs its value to look like this:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Company\Program\component\settings] 
"FullPath"=hex:43,3A,5C,55,73,65,72,73,5C,44,65,76,69,6E,5C,41,\
70,70,44,61,74,61,5C,4C,6F,63,61,6C,5C,54,65,6D,70,5C,6C,69,62,\
46,69,6C,65,2E,64,6C,6C
```

I've tried countless times trying to insert "`\`" after so many characters but to no avail. I've tried the following command:

```
reg add "%tree%" /v FullPath /t REG_BINARY /d %hex%
```

Which I added before the bottom half of the batch script which just takes the final converted hex string and adds a "`,`" every two characters. Reluctantly, trying to use `reg` to add the value into the registry directly is for whatever reason not working either.

### Question

---

So now that I've broken down after countless hours of frustration; I ask you fellow *Stack Overflowians* (lol) is there something I'm not doing correctly? Is there something I'm leaving out or missing? Is there a better way to get this string to hex into a reg file so I can import this reg file after a certain function in the installer completes?

#### **The Batch Script**

**str2hex2reg.bat**

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:stringToHex
set /P "=%~1" < NUL > chr.tmp

for %%a in (chr.tmp) do fsutil file createnew zero.tmp %%~Za > NUL

set "hex="
for /F "skip=1 tokens=2" %%a in ('fc /B chr.tmp zero.tmp') do set "hex=!hex!%%a"

del chr.tmp zero.tmp

set Text=%hex%
set output=

for /L %%I in (0,2,500) do (
    call set Letter=!Text:~%%I,2!
    if not "!Letter!" == "" (
        set output=!output!,!Letter!
    ) else (
        goto finished
    )
)

:finished
set output=%output:~1,999%
set ver=Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
set tree=[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Company\Program\component\settings]
set key1="FullPath"=hex:%output%

@echo %ver% > import.reg
@echo. >> import.reg
@echo %tree% >> import.reg
@echo %key1% >> import.reg

endlocal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str2hex2reg.bat C:\Users\Devin\AppData\Local\Temp\libFile.dll
```

With this changed last lines:

```
 >"import.reg" echo %ver% 
>>"import.reg" echo.
>>"import.reg" echo %tree%
:loop
If "%key1:~63%" neq "" (
>>"import.reg" echo %key1:~0,63%\
set "key1=!Key1:~63!"
Goto :loop
)
>>"import.reg" echo %key1%
```

will output:

```
> type import.reg
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Company\Program\component\settings]
"FullPath"=hex:43,3A,5C,55,73,65,72,73,5C,44,65,76,69,6E,5C,41,\
70,70,44,61,74,61,5C,4C,6F,63,61,6C,5C,54,65,6D,70,5C,6C,69,62,\
46,69,6C,65,2E,64,6C,6C
```

Comment: I was trying a whole bunch of different things using the number 63. At least I was on to something. You're gentleman and a scholar, my friend! Thanks @LotPings